# Python - how to overwrite output from Markdown library

Tags: python, markdown

I have following problem, i'm using markdown library for my webapp and i need to modify the output generated by it, namely i want to change default `<img src="...">` tag into `<img data-src="...">`. What would be the best way to change the html generated by this module?

Comment: Have a look here for inspiration: https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/blob/master/markdown/treeprocessors.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use Python-Markdown's [Extension API](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/api.html). Most people use the API to add their own syntax, but it can alter the existing output just as easily. That way, you can use Markdown's parser but get your desired output. No need for wrappers or parsing twice.

In your case, you want to override (subclass) the [ImagePattern](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/blob/d18c3d0acab0e7469c3284c897afcb61f9dd1fea/markdown/inlinepatterns.py#L585) class and define your own Element which is returned by the `handleMatch` method. Then you just need to [tell Markdown about it](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/api.html#integrating_into_markdown). In your case, the regex doesn't even need to be different. Just import and reuse the existing [`IMAGE_LINK_RE`](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/blob/d18c3d0acab0e7469c3284c897afcb61f9dd1fea/markdown/inlinepatterns.py#L62) and override [`inlinePatterns["image_link"]`](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/blob/d18c3d0acab0e7469c3284c897afcb61f9dd1fea/markdown/inlinepatterns.py#L121).

This [tutorial](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/wiki/Tutorial-2---Altering-Markdown-Rendering) should get you started. While it is implementing a different syntax, the basics are the same and it is a lot shorter than the API docs. See also [part 1](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/wiki/Tutorial-1---Writing-Extensions-for-Python-Markdown).

For completeness, if you use the reference syntax for you images, you would need to do the same thing with the [ImageReferencePattern](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/blob/d18c3d0acab0e7469c3284c897afcb61f9dd1fea/markdown/inlinepatterns.py#L63). You may find it easier to implement as a [TreeProcessor](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/api.html#treeprocessors) instead (which I believe is what @Kos was referring to in his comment to the original post). That way the existing parser builds the existing output, but before serializing the ElementTree to text, you can loop through all the `img` tags and alter them to fit your needs. As an example, the [HeaderId Extension](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/blob/master/markdown/extensions/headerid.py#L141) does this to add IDs to h1-6 tags.

Comment: The tutorial link broke. The key points should have been imported.

Comment: The tutorial link is unbroken now (2022-02-03).